# Skilled worker visa to UK after study visa refusal in 2018

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I applied for a **Canadian** English study visa in 2016 and got refused ( Applied from KSA I am from another country and I am working in KSA ) with the following

“You have not satisfied me that you will leave Canada at the end of your stay. In reaching this decision, I considered several factors, Including:

- Immigration status in your country of residence.
- Length of proposed stay in Canada
- Purpose of visit
- Current employment situation

In 2018 I got English study visa refusal from **UK** after applying from my country ( mentioned that I was refused in Canada visa in my application ), I was working remotely for a company in KSA and provided all the required employment letter and payment slips and bank statement with more than 100k USD.

Unfortunately I got the rejection letter saying that I the officer found that I don’t have strong ties to my country.

Now I got job offer from an eligible company in UK as a Software Engineer and salary will be 80K GBP in London mentioned in the contract, and I am applying for a skilled worker visa and will mention the past two refusals.
The company is offering Certificate of sponsorship and listed in “ Register of licensed sponsors: workers” page

I am really worried because it is a good offer, would the previous refusals affect my chances of getting the skilled worker visa ?

——————
Update: got my visa :)

Comment: Do you have a genuine "certificate of sponsorship"? If yes then the chances of being turned down for a 80K GBP (I presume that's in pounds) job is insanely low, that's a _lot_ of money. At that sort of money, two study visa refusals is nothing. This is not an answer because I have no source just hearsay.

Comment: Yes I have a genuine certificate of sponsorship and the company is listed in “ Register of licensed sponsors: workers” page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A study visa is time-limited and requires the holder to leave at the end of the study period. While a skilled worker visa is also initially time-limited (for up to 5 years) it can be extended or updated when it expires or, if you change jobs or employer, and you can apply to extend your visa as many times as you like as long as you still meet the eligibility requirements. So the need to show ties to home country isn’t relevant, making it unlikely that your previous refusals will have much/any bearing if you meet all the eligibility criteria for the skilled worker visa.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa